# Export option doesn't work on Google Pixel device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We have developed an `Xamarin.Forms` application. We provide option to export file to other apps to explore it. Exported mobi format file to Kindle in Google Pixel device, it couldn't upload in Kindle but this process works in other Android devices. We have used PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities process to list the installed app for export process. Please provide valiable suggestion for this.

Code Snippet:

```
var mobileFileName = Path.Combine(path, m_documentName);
var shareIntentsLists = new List<Intent>();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                sendIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
                sendIntent.SetPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
                sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + mobileFileName));

Intent chooserIntent = new Intent();
                chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Share with");
                chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mobileFileName));
                if (shareIntentsLists.Count > 0)
                {
                    chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, shareIntentsLists.ToArray());
                }
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Regards,
Cheran

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: By `export file to other apps`, do you mean share file in apps? Please show your codes.

Comment: Yes, sharing file to other apps. I have added code snippet in above query itself. Please suggest on this.